# Question about the derive of a theory of the scaling function in the wavelet analysis

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelet

Page 5 in [link](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/isyebayes/bank/handout20.pdf):

> For the scaling function, it holds: $\int \phi(x)dx = 1 $ or,
> equivalently: $\Phi(0) = 1$

How is this derived?

Comment: Are you asking about the derivation of the first equation or the equivalency of the first and the second ?

Comment: @Hilmar I am asking about the derivation of the first equation.